# SQL SERVER : having two where conditions in one update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I want to update a table with one update statement. However I have two where conditions. Meaning say the table in question (tableA) has 5 columns out of which 3 columns are updated using tableB and rest 2 are updating using tableC.
For example:

```
update A
Set col1 = B.colx,
    col2 = B.coly,
    col3 = B.colz
From TableA A
  INNER JOIN TableB B
  ON A.col = B.colr
 Where B.colw = 'xx' AND B.colu = 'yy'


Update A
SET col4 = C.Cola
    col5 = C.Colb
FROM tableA A
 Inner join tableC C
 ON A.col= C.cols
WHERE C.colk= 'ddd' and C.colj = 'lll'
```

Please help ! Thanks !

-------   Suggested code -----

Can I use ?

```
update A
    Set col1 = B.colx,
        col2 = B.coly,
        col3 = B.colz,
        col4 = C.Cola,
        col5 = C.Colb
    From TableA A
      INNER JOIN TableB B
      ON A.col = B.colr
          INNER JOIN TableC C
          ON A.col=C.cols
     Where (B.colw = 'xx' AND B.colu = 'yy') OR (C.colk= 'ddd' and C.colj = 'lll')
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What specifically is not working?

Comment: I don't know if this is also true in sql, in mysql you can not select from a table and update it at the same time.

Comment: Why do you want to combine two separate update statements which update two distinct sets of columns into one update statement?  What is it you think that would buy you?

Comment: Why would you want to do this with only one update statement?

Comment: Because It is giving me a violation of the primary key constraint. I can't change the table schema and the problem will be gone by using one update statement.

Comment: I added a code. Please suggest if that code would work. Thanks !

Comment: the code seems fine. just wrap in a begin tran, your update, a few selects to confirm, and a rollback and run to check it. if it doesn't work properly, no harm done.

Answer (score 0):

```
 update tableA
 set columnA = (select columnD from tableB
 where tableA.ID = tableB.ID),
 set columnB = (select columnD from tableC
 where tableA.ID = tableC.ID)
 where exists ... etc
```

I agree there isn't much value add to this approach versus breaking out into individual DML statements.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for sth like this :

```
update A 
left join B on( A.col = B.colr AND  B.colw = 'xx' AND B.colu = 'yy')
left join C on( A.col= C.cols AND C.colk= 'ddd' and C.colj = 'lll')
Set A.col1 = B.colx,
    A.col2 = B.coly,
    A.col3 = B.colz,
    A.col4 = C.Cola,
    A.col5 = C.Colb ;
```

Answer (score -1):

it may be that you can not select from a table and update it at the same time.

in database parlance select means read just as update means write.

### by specifying: "A" in the "on" clause, you are reading "A"

EDIT:

```
 update A
Set col1 = B.colx,
    col2 = B.coly,
    col3 = B.colz,
    col4 = C.Cola,
    col5 = C.Colb
From (SELECT * FROM TableA) D, TableB B, TableC C
  WHERE D.col = B.colr
      AND D.col=C.cols
      AND ((B.colw = 'xx' AND B.colu = 'yy') OR (C.colk= 'ddd' and C.colj = 'lll'))
```

Comment: Where's the select statement?

Comment: @RobS, see update. Your code has " ON A.col= C.cols" that's reading/selecting from "A"

Comment: I added a code to the question. Please suggest if that code would work. Thanks !

Comment: May I assume that "A.col" may mean "A.col6" to continue your pattern?

Comment: @RobS, are you serious? you read my post, right? in a database there are READS and there are WRITES. down-voting is your right.

Comment: No, I'm using case statement for col4 and col 5. This is serving the purpose for now. Thanks